# Error while compiling softwares using make: cannot find -lXm, -lXt, -lX11

Tags: compiling, root, make

make compilation showing errors like

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [candle] Error 1
make: *** [candle] Error 2
```

I am not understanding this problem and I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 bit operating system 
but it works in x32 bit operating system

Comment: Have you installed the prerequisite X11 development packages?

Answer (score 2):

First you try with above command, If it not works then you download and install the following .deb files for 32 bit operating system

```
candle_3.2-98_i386.deb
candle_3.4-99_i386.deb
libmotif4_2.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
libxp_1.0.0-9_i386.deb
openmotif_2.3.1-1_i386.deb
openmotif-devel_2.3.1-1_i386.deb
```

For 64 bit operating system you need to change the FLAG option from TRUE to FALSE into the program.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, please run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxt-dev libmotif-dev
```